# Cannot connect to remote desktop after applying MS12-020

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

After applying the [MS12-020](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-020) fix this morning (as it seemed a real **big** issue) I'm not able to remote connect to the server anymore. The RDP client timeouts and nothing is logged on the server.

Comment: First step would be to get alternative access to the machine ASAP.

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: Lol, for sure that I did. But good remainder anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since the binary file is modified, it might be Windows Firewall not catching up with the new checksum, or the AV sandboxing perceived a backdoor on your system.

MS12-20 also changes RDP registry, thus you might need to redo your configuration anew.

Comment: I will check these things. ANyway I expected to find lots of people with the same problem but looks like I'm alone with this.

Comment: Looking at my server the RDP port 3389 is not opened. The Terminal Services service is started and running.

Comment: Anything in antivirus logs about quarantine and sandbox of possible trojan (or exclude terminal server executable from antivirus processing)

Comment: I don't have an antivius installed.

Comment: so dig the log for windows firewall events.

Comment: Even the port is not openend on the server (checked with netstat -ano) :? Nothing loged on the firewall as the port is not opened.

Comment: run tsadmin, change some config parameter, exit, then change it back. then go to services and restart terminal service. may help to fix registry.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was related with the remote server being virtualized by Parallels Virtuozo. Looks like you cannot update the system without updating the host first.

That's all I can say 'cos the details are only known by my virtual server provider.

Comment: For future reference, you really should have mentioned that it wasn't a conventional Windows install.  Virtuozo subverts the operating system in a way that seems likely to lead to all sorts of problems, including this one.  (I presume it works well when used as designed, but it's not really Windows.)

Comment: I agree, but I was not aware of this. I'm just renting a virtual server.